# Accessing contents of char** on a windows x64 cause exception

Tags: c, windows, pointers

The following piece of code is causing an exception on a windows vista x64 and i can't figure why.

```
size_t pBaseAddr;
char *lpszFuncName;
IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *pExportDir;
const char **lpszNames;
unsigned int dwIndex;

lpszNames  = ((const char **)(pBaseAddr + pExportDir->AddressOfNames));
if(lpszNames == NULL)
  return NULL;

for(dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < pExportDir->NumberOfFunctions; dwIndex++)
{ 
   if(strcmp((char *)(pBaseAddr + lpszNames[dwIndex]), lpszFuncName) == 0)
       return Something;
}
```

The problem, i think, is on the strcmp() line, specifically on lpszNames[dwIndex]. It works on 32 bits but on 64 it crashes with a access violation.
if you want to see the whole code [check my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766031/differences-in-code-between-windows-32-bits-and-64-bits)

EDIT: since people didn't look at the link i posted on the question I will post the entire code from the original question.

```
// Retrieve NT header from base address.
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *GetNtHeaderFromBase( void *pBaseAddr )
{
 IMAGE_DOS_HEADER       *pDosHeader;
 IMAGE_NT_HEADERS       *pNtHeaders;

 pDosHeader = ((IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)pBaseAddr);
 if(pDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
  return NULL;

 pNtHeaders = ((IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((DWORD)pBaseAddr + pDosHeader->e_lfanew));
 if(pNtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
  return NULL;

 return ((pNtHeaders == NULL) ? NULL : pNtHeaders);
}


// This emulates GetProcAddress.
void *GetFuncAddr( size_t pBaseAddr, char *lpszFuncName ) 
{
 IMAGE_NT_HEADERS       *pNtHeaders;
 IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY   *pDataDir;
 IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *pExportDir;
 const char      **lpszNames;
 size_t       *lpdwFuncs, dwIndex;

 pNtHeaders = GetNtHeaderFromBase((void *)pBaseAddr);
 if(pNtHeaders == NULL)
  return NULL;

 pDataDir = ((IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY *)(pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT));
 if(pDataDir == NULL)
  return NULL;

 pExportDir = ((IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *)(pBaseAddr + pDataDir->VirtualAddress));
 if(pExportDir == NULL)
  return NULL;

 lpdwFuncs  = ((size_t *)(pBaseAddr + pExportDir->AddressOfFunctions));
 lpszNames  = ((const char **)(pBaseAddr + pExportDir->AddressOfNames));
 if(lpdwFuncs == NULL || lpszNames == NULL)
  return NULL;

 for(dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < pExportDir->NumberOfFunctions; dwIndex++)
 { 
  // decrypt funcname and get the address
  if(strcmp((char *)(pBaseAddr + lpszNames[dwIndex]), lpszFuncName) == 0)
   return (void*)(pBaseAddr + lpdwFuncs[dwIndex]);
 }

 return NULL;
}
```

EDIT2: NO, i am NOT using DWORD.

Comment: Did you omit code? Because in the above code, `pExportDir->AddressOfNames` already invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Well you're not initializing pBaseAddr...

Comment: pBaseAddress is being passed as an argument to the function. That's why I placed a link to the original code.

Comment: @sbi, what do you mean undefined behavior?

Comment: Please check the code I added to the question

Comment: It would be easier if you could cut it down to code that reproduces the problem that other people could compile and run too.

Comment: You are still casting pBaseAddress to a DWORD in GetNtHeaderFromBase(). size_t would be more appropriate (for the same reason you do not want to store an address in a DWORD).

Comment: I did and people kept on saying that I didn't post the entire thing. so here it is

Comment: @RaphaelSP I changed the casting of DWORD to size_t and still gives me the same problem. again the problem is on the line i mentioned on the question

Comment: Have you tried using IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 instead ?

Comment: yes, when you compile the binary for 64 bit, that struct gets filled automatically (according to MS) but i went ahead and I hardcoded it. still the same.

Comment: see if this code can help you: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Misc/Q_21066562.html

Comment: that definitely helped, thanks! if you can place that as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: no... sorry, when I try to get the address of the function the it won't work on x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void GetFuncAddr(HMODULE hBaseAddr, char *pFuncName) 
{
    unsigned int count = 1;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *pDosHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pNtHeaders;
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER *pOptionalHeader;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY *pDataDirectory;
    IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *pExp;
    ULONG * addrofnames;
    char *funcname;
    ULONG *funcaddr;
    
    pDosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)hBaseAddr; 

    if (pDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) 
    { 
        return NULL;
    } 

    pNtHeaders = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)(((BYTE *)pDosHeader) + pDosHeader->e_lfanew); 

    if (pNtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    { 
        return NULL;
    } 

    pOptionalHeader = &pNtHeaders->pOptionalHeader; 
    pDataDirectory = &pOptionalHeader->pDataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]; 

    pExp = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *)((size_t)pDosHeader + pDataDirectory->VirtualAddress); 

    addrofnames = (ULONG *)((BYTE*) hBaseAddr + pExp->addrofnames);
    funcaddr = (ULONG*) ((BYTE*) hBaseAddr + pExp->AddressOfFunctions);

    for(count = 0; count < pExp->NumberOfNames; count++)
    {
        funcname = (char*)((BYTE*) hBaseAddr + addrofnames[count]);     
        if(strcmp(funcname, pFuncName) == 0)
        {   
            return (void*)((BYTE*) hBaseAddr + funcaddr[count]);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An access violation means that you're probably trying to dereference a null pointer in the `lpszNames` array.

`lpszNames[dwIndex]` is returning a `char *`, that probably is not pointing to valid data.

Can you verify that `lpszNames[dwIndex]` does not return null?

Actually, it may not even have to be null, it could just be an address defined as in 'protected' memory.

Comment: no, because whenever I tried to run any line of code that has lpszNames[dwIndex] it causes the crash. I added a NULL check and now it's crashing on that line

Comment: how are you checking for null?  lpszNames[dwIndex] == NULL should not cause an access violation?

Comment: I wasn't I was it was the same line that it's causing the problem (the strcmp)

Comment: Is it a valid data location though, or is it pointing to protected memory?

Comment: That is the big question. I can't print the pointer (%p) because it crashes, i can't print the contents (%s) because it crashes, I can print in hex (%X) but it doesn't really disclose anything

Comment: What does the debugger tell you ? `<Bad pointer>`, or something that could make sense ?

Comment: just access violation. i don't have any debugger that i can install on that 64 bit machine

Comment: The value in hex should show you if it's in low memory.. print the hex value of the 'good' pointers too and see if they're relatively close...

Comment: This is as much information as I can get from that machine: Unhandled exception at 0x00000001400011c0 in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.
Then at that address you have
 movzx       edx,byte ptr [rax]

Comment: There are no good pointers. it crashes on the 1st iteration of the for

Comment: I think is the pBaseAddr. I am getting that by calling LoadLibraryEx("kernel32.dll", NULL, 0);

Comment: I installed a debugger on the x64 Windows and it's giving me a bad pointer error when I tried to see what's inside

Answer (score 0):

```
pNtHeaders = ((IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((DWORD)pBaseAddr + pDosHeader->e_lfanew));
if(pNtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
 return NULL;
```

You are casting a pointer to `DWORD`. This is not safe on 64-bit systems where a `DWORD` is half the size of a pointer. I'm not sure if this is the root of your problems, but it's definitely unsafe.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the rest of the comments you'll see that I already corrected this.